# If $g(x) = x^2 + 3x + 1$ and $f \circ g = g\circ f$, then $f$ and $g$ intersect on the line $y = x$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, solution-verification, function-and-relation-composition

> Let $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, $g(x) = x^2 + 3x + 1$ and $f∘g=g∘f$.
>
> Prove that $Cf, Cg$ and the line $y=x$ have at least one common point.

My solution:

$fog=gof$ then $f=g$, $Df = Dg = \mathbb R$ and $f(x) = g(x)$

I fear that the above assumption is wrong..

But if it is correct, here is the rest of the solution.

Then $f(x) = g(x) = x^2 + 3x + 1$

Let $f(x)=y$ then $x^2 + 3x + 1 = y$

for $x=y$ we get: $x^2 + 3x + 1 = x$

$x^2 + 2x + 1 = 0$

$(x+1)^2 = 0$

$x = -1$

Because $x=y$ the common point is $(-1,-1)$

Comment: What does $Cf$ mean? (And I assume that $fog$ means $f\circ g$.)

Comment: The graph of the function f. Your assumption is correct.

Comment: Let $f(x)$ be identically equal to $-1$. Then $f\circ g$ is identically equal to $-1$, and so is $g\circ f$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice that the graphs of $g(x) = x^2 + 3x + 1$ and $y = x$ intersect at precisely one point: $(-1, -1)$. In other words, we know that:
$$\boxed{
g(x) = x \iff x = -1
} \tag{$\star$}$$
To obtain our common point, it is enough to show that $f(-1) = -1$.

To this end, let $k = f(-1)$ and suppose that $f \circ g = g\circ f$. Then in particular, we know that both functions agree at $x = -1$ so that:
$$
g(k) = g(f(-1)) = f(g(-1)) = f(-1) = k
$$

Hence, by $(\star)$, we conclude that $f(-1) = k = -1$, as desired. $~~\blacksquare$

Comment: Thanks, is my assumption wrong though?

Comment: [As André pointed out,](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426318/is-my-solution-acceptable-function-problem/1426328?noredirect=1#comment2905578_1426318) the assumption that $f = g$ can sometimes be wrong.

Comment: You just saved me a lot of typing, Adriano! (I was starting to type up your observation $(\star)$.)